# Huge variation of values in the input to ConvLSTM2D

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm

My input to a ConvLSTM2D layer is a 2D array with two parts concatenated vertically. The top 36 rows have an average value of 5, while the bottom 125 rows have an average value of 5000. So the bottom portion is three orders of magnitude higher than the top portion.

After training, my network seems to be insensitive to the different inputs at different time steps during prediction. This is, the predicted output is the same at all 6 time steps. I'm using a ReLU activation function and Keras for building, training and testing the network.

Could this have been caused by the huge variation in the input values?

Comment: Could be. What happens if you scale the data beforehand to have mean 0 and variance 1?

Comment: That would be tough to do since the two concatenated data are from different domains. The whole thing would be solved if I could feed the output at timestep t as an input at t+1 for a ConvLSTM2D. I found some examples of how to do it for a conventional LSTM but not for a convolutional LSTM.

Comment: Why not scale the 2 data sources separately?